# Is this approach correct in forecasting with ARIMA(1,0,0) models with covariates?

Tags: regression, forecasting, arima, predictor

I fitted an arima(1,0,0) model with covariates to my data set in R. 
I have a response variable y and sets of covariates $w,x,z$ and $z^2$ which are continuous. I wish to make forecast using the fitted model. See my steps below:

Steps:
(1) After fitting the final model, i.e arima(1,0,0) with non-zero mean, I used the 'forecast' package in R to forecast for the next 5 observations for y using the last 5 recent observed values for each of the covariates.

(2) Now, I wish to forecast the value of y for the next 5 periods using the same model in step (1) above if I set the values of $z$ and $z^2$ to zero(0), i.e setting z<-rep(0,5) and $z^2$<-rep(0,5) while keeping the last 5 recent observed values for w and x.

The goal here is to find out how the next 5 forecast values of y will compare when we set z=0,$z^2$=0 (step 2) and when we did not set them to zero (0)(step 1).
This approach is applicable in standard regression.

I wish to know if this procedure is correct in time series analysis.

Comment: Please note that an ARIMA(0,0,0) model is just white noise

Comment: Furthermore you are writing ARIMA(0,0,0) in the heading and ARIMA(1,0,0) in the body. Is one of those models a typo?

Comment: Thanks @Ferdi. The model is arima(1,0,0) and not the white noise arima(0,0,0). I made the necessary edits in the headline.

Comment: @Ferdi they may be different if there is a non-zero mean. "Noise" implies zero mean.